# Clean Google Cardboard SDK project won't compile

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-vr

What I did:

1. I created new project using Unity 3D
2. switched target to iOS
3. imported new custom asset "GoogleVRForUnity unitypackage"
4. created new blank C# behaviour script
5. hit "compile" in MonoDeveloper

What I got: **Compile error** "The type or namespace name "Xcode" does not exist in the namespace "UnityEditor.iOS. Are you missing an assembly reference?"
in

> using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;

in /Assets/GoogleVR/Legacy/Editor/GvrViewerEditor.cs

I changed nothing. Is this a bug? How to fix this?

When I build for iOS from Unity Editor, run XCODE project on my device, everything works as expected.

[image]

OS X 10.11.6 (15G31), Unity 5.4.0f3, Google VR SDK seems to be latest (downloaded repo directly from "https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download")
Of course I have "iOS build support" component.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

Should've added .NET reference to:

> "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/iOSSupport/UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode.dll"

I wonder why it wasn't referenced in the first place.